# Hex string to binary in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, binary, type-conversion

I am doing an encryption cipher which requires to read a hex key from file and convert it to `bytes[]` array.

The only way to do it, as I have found out, is to read lines from a file (with bufferedReader), create hex String array from them and convert each hex string array member to a binary string which can later be converted to a byte using parseByte.

To be more clear:

- read line
- get hex array
- convert to binary
- convert to byte)

So, basically, it looks like this: `hex[i]` is a string from hex array.

```
requiredByte[i] = Byte.parseByte(hexToBinary(hex[i]), 2);
```

So, to my method to work I need to read hex key from file and convert it into binary strings.

Key in hex looks like this (yes, both lines are the same):

> 01 23 45 67 89 AB CD EF
>
> 01 23 45 67 89 AB CD EF

I need to convert it to this binary Key:

> 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111
>
> 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
>
> 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111
>
> 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111

However, the fifth hex number is `89`, what is `137` as an integer. And you can only convert numbers between `-127` and `127` into a binary string.

When I try to convert hex number 89 in my own way, I get this message in console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out
>   of range. Value:"100011" Radix:16

Do you guys have any ideas of how I could convert hex to binary or even how could I convert hex `String[]` array to `byte[]` array?

Comment: represent each digit as 4 bits (aka a [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)). Then your "fifth hex number" is `8` and `9` (or `1000` and `1001`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you explain more on how to do this? I've tried searching on how to represent numbers as 4 bits but failed. Any information would be highly appreciated

Comment: you absolutely do **not** need to convert the hex values to binary before converting them to bytes;  you have several options to avoid doing that

Comment: @landru27 saw that post, didn't find an answer to my question. Sorry if it looks like a duplicate

Comment: @landru27 could you give me some examples of how can I convert hex string directly into byte?

Comment: @LiJonas : your question begins with "I am doing an encryption cipher which requires to read a hex key from file and convert it to bytes[] array.";  that other post begins with "I am looking for a way to convert a long string (from a dump), that represents hex values into a byte array."  can you explain how these are different?

Comment: @landru27 the main answer was not working when I was testing so I presumed my issue is different. I will double check this later and delete my post in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you use a fairly simple method [`BigInteger::toString(int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString-int-) which returns the String representation in the given radix. Use `2` for the binary representation.

```
// 100100011010001010110011110001001101010111100110111101111
new BigInteger("0123456789ABCDEF", 16).toString(2);
```

Note the String must be blank characters free and using this way you have to process them from the array each one-by-one.

Comment: Yup, that's a good solution for the entire problem. Mine solves just the parsing part.

Comment: Be aware that it is missing the initial prefix of 7 zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing using `Byte.parseByte` using a larger type such as `Integer`. `Integer.parseInt` will work fine, and you can just cast the result to a byte if that's what you need.

But remember that printing that byte will show you a negative number. If you want to see it as an unsigned value, do a bitwise and with `0xff` like this:

```
byte b = 0xff;
System.out.println(b & 0xff); //Will print 255 instead of -1
```